# Openpyxl Vlookup - Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Why does this vlookup not work? after running the script the "P" column stay blank. what am I doing wrong?

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('inv.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook['Price']
Price = workbook.get_sheet_by_name("Price")

## Create a dictionary of column names
ColNames = {}
Current  = 0
for COL in worksheet.iter_cols(1, worksheet.max_column):
    ColNames[COL[0].value] = Current
    Current += 1

    
def vlook():
    for row in Price["P:P"]: #the column where I want the new data to be. (this is where i would type in the vlookup formula in excel) sheet name is "Price" & column is "P"
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(A{0}, 'Parts'!A3:F59748,3,FALSE)".format(cell.row)  
vlook()

            
         
for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows():
    print(row_cells[ColNames['Unit Price']].value)
workbook.save("inv.xlsx")
```

This is the formula I used in excel & it works perfectly fine:`=VLOOKUP(A4,Parts!A3:F59748,3,FALSE)`

Comment: where is your `vlook` call?

Comment: Thnaks for pointing that out, I added vlook() to the code and now im getting this error:

TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable